# Mesh Edit Mode showing covered vertices

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, edit-mode

I don't really know how explain this, but I did this: [image: Covered border lines are showing]

Somebody can explain me this? I'm beginner and it's my second problem with editing mesh view.

Comment: If you are a beginner you should bookmark the link for the blender manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/ and read through it. In this case what you are looking for is called [**limit selection to visible**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html?highlight=limit%20selection%20visible#limit-selection-to-visible)

Comment: The effect what I show you is symilar to limit selection to visible, but it's work only for border verticies. I want turn off it, but I dont know how to do this.

Comment: Somebody have any idea?